# Angularjs realtime h1 check on textarea

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible with Angularjs to check a textarea if there is a h1 present and give a realtime message.

So for example when i'm typing a text it will give me realtime a reminder that if forget to use a h1 tag.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, is possible!
You just need to set a ng-model in your textarea eg: ng-model="myText", in your controller you can define a function(checkTag) to test "h1" and do something you need. You also need to set a angular event to trigger the function when you typing, I choosen keypress envent. See the code bellow.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.sometext = "Volvo";
    
    $scope.checkTag = function(tag){
      if($scope.sometext.indexOf(tag) > 0){
          $scope.message = "Found "+tag+"!";
      }
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <textarea rows="4" cols="50" ng-model="sometext" ng-keypress='checkTag("h1")'>
    
  </textarea>
 
<h1>{{sometext}}</h1>
<h2>{{message}}</h2>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```